# How can you use managed (unified) memory for an image?

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda, gpu-managed-memory

I have spent all day yesterday reading how to use managed (unified) memory array for a CUDA program (using the book [Professional CUDA Programming](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Professional+CUDA+C+Programming-p-9781118739327), practiced some of the sample code (although I still got doubts about the profiler info) and I am ready to apply it to my program that uses both a CUDA kernel and some OpenCV functions.

I have several questions, but let me address here the first one.

I have

```
cv::Mat h_image;
h_image = cv::imread(dirname+image_filenames[ni], cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

cv::cuda::GpuMat d_image;
// 2. Upload the Image
d_image.upload(h_image);
```

So I have an image read with `imread` and I upload it to the device memory.
How can I use unified memory for this?

In theory, to use unified memory I can have (with float arrays)

```
float *A;
cudaMallocManaged((void **)&A, nBytes);
```

or even (and I prefer this)

```
__device__ __managed__ float A[67108864];
```

Is there a way to do something similar with Mats and GpuMats?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to this (have not tried it yet) [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/eliminate-upload-download-for-opencv-cuda-gpumat-using-shared-memory/83090/4?u=kansai) and actually a very good answer since it explains both using unified memory and pinned memory

It basically uses this

```
#ifndef USE_UNIFIED_MEM
    /* Pinned memory. No cache */
    std::cout << "Using pinned memory" << std::endl;
    void *device_ptr, *host_ptr;
    cudaSetDeviceFlags(cudaDeviceMapHost);
    cudaHostAlloc((void **)&host_ptr, frameByteSize, cudaHostAllocMapped);
    cudaHostGetDevicePointer((void **)&device_ptr, (void *) host_ptr , 0);
    cv::Mat frame_out(height, width, CV_8UC3, host_ptr);
    cv::cuda::GpuMat d_frame_out(height, width, CV_8UC3, device_ptr);
#else
    /* Unified memory */
    std::cout << "Using unified memory" << std::endl;
    void *unified_ptr;
    cudaMallocManaged(&unified_ptr, frameByteSize);
    cv::Mat frame_out(height, width, CV_8UC3, unified_ptr);
    cv::cuda::GpuMat d_frame_out(height, width, CV_8UC3, unified_ptr);
#endif
```

I am going to try this but without allocating it dynamically but with `__device__ __managed__` too

Answer (score 1):

This is another option which well make all CV mat use shared memory

```
cv::Mat::setDefaultAllocator(cv::cuda::HostMem::getAllocator(cv::cuda::HostMem::AllocType::SHARED));
```